# Angular ng-Model not showing up second time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have this code inside a modal popup that is shown under certain circumstances, the first time the modal is shown everything is working normal.

I have this code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <p>First Name:</p>
    {{vm.user.name_first}}
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.name_first" name="firstName" required />
</div>
```

After closing the modal and opening again, the text below the `p` is shown correctly, however, the `ng-model` (which has the same content after the `p`), is showing the input empty instead of the content of `vm.user.name_first`.

What can be happening that only affects the second time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="form-group">
<p>First Name:</p>
{{vm.user.name_first}}
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.name_first" name="firstName" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" required />
```

Explanation:

> Sometimes it's helpful to bind ngModel to a getter/setter function. A getter/setter is a function that returns a representation of the model when called with zero arguments, and sets the internal state of a model when called with an argument. It's sometimes useful to use this for models that have an internal representation that's different from what the model exposes to the view.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel -> last paragraph

Comment: It may be a solution but this answer doesn't provide any insight into what you've actually changed and why this works.